# Qiskit: Taking a QUBO matrix into `qubit_op'

Tags: programming, qiskit, qaoa

I'm trying to solve the maximum independent set problem using Qiskit and the QAOA.

I've a nice QUBO Matrix for this simple path graph:

[image: Nice Graph]

as so:

[image]

My question is, how do I convert this into a general DOCPLEX method which can be put into the `QuadracticProgram` method of Qiskit? How can this be done for a general QUBO matrix?

I realise that for this particular problem I've found the matrix $Q$ as described in this [guide].(https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1811/1811.11538.pdf)

So by doing the matrix multiplication:

$$y=x^{t} Q x$$

where $$ x = \begin{pmatrix} x_{0} \\  x_{1} \\  x_{2} \end{pmatrix} $$

gives the expression:

$$ y = -x_{0}^{2} -x_{1}^{2}  -x_{2}^{2}  + 2x_{0}x_{1} + 2x_{1}x_{2} $$

which I want to minimise (EDIT: Changed from maximise - whoops !). As the nodes are either in the maximum set or not,  the variables are binary and so $  x_{0}= x_{0}^{2}$ (NB am I correct in thinking for solving the Maximum weighted independent set problem, say where $ x_{0} $ was twice as important, the weight would manifest as a different constant for the quadractic term?)

Is a function that can take a general matrix into DOCPLEX form qiskit can recognise and operate on?

EDIT 2:

I don't think the `stable_set.get_operator()` method works at all.
For the simplest example

```
path = nx.to_numpy_array(nx.path_graph(3))


qubitOp, offset = stable_set.get_operator(path)
print('Offset:', offset)
print('Ising Hamiltonian:')
print(qubitOp.print_details())
```

gives:

[image]

which is not the correct function - the weights of the different nodes are not equal -  and so has no hope of finding the right result.

EDIT 3: After a little bug hunt, the problem is nearly solved !
https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aqua/issues/1553

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lena's answer doesn't work as we've noted in the comments underneath: the `stable_set.get_operator()` takes in a numpy adjacency matrix which is not what I'm inputting.

Instead I've written a function which takes the `qubo_array` I've got and creates a QuadracticProgram exactly.

To do the particular program I was after manually is done as so:

```
mdl = Model('docplex model')

x_0 = mdl.binary_var('x_0')
x_1 = mdl.binary_var('x_1')
x_2= mdl.binary_var('x_2')

mdl.minimize( -x_0 - x_1  - x_2 + 2*x_0*x_1 + 2*x_2*x_1)


print(mdl.export_as_lp_string())
```

The way I figured to do this for larger matrices automatically was the use of this function.

```
def the_auto_doco_mod(qubo_array,model_name,constant):

    """

    Function that takes the   QUBO array created for a graphing problem and converts it to a docplex model
    ready for qiskit

    Directly consrtructs the quadractic program with reference to this page
    """
    number_of_variables = len(qubo_array[1]) # gets the number of variables from the length of the square qubo matrix
    #mdl = Model('model_name')
    mod = QuadraticProgram()

    for variable in range(0,number_of_variables): # creates the binary variables from the size of the matrix 
        var_name = "x_" +str(variable)
        mod.binary_var(name =var_name)

    mod.minimize(constant = 2,quadratic =qubo_array)  # can put in all constraints as quadractic as the binary variables mean that x_0 ^ 2 = x_0 in both cases 
                                                    #  not sure of the impact of this on performance however 

    print(mod.export_as_lp_string())
```

Does anyone know whether constructing the QuadracticProgram this way will mean that the ising model taken in by qiskit will evaluate slower or  be affected in any other way?

Answer (score 5):

There is actually a nice way in Qiskit to transform a matrix of an optimization problem into an qubit operator that can be translated into a quadratic program. I'll put here the example, note this is possible for many optimization problems, find every one [here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/qiskit.optimization.applications.ising.html) in case you want to test something else! For example [here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/optimization/6_examples_max_cut_and_tsp.html) it is done for MaxCut and TSP, it could show you with other examples how to do what I did here !

```
import numpy as np

from qiskit import Aer
from qiskit.optimization.applications.ising import stable_set
from qiskit.aqua.algorithms import VQE, NumPyMinimumEigensolver, QAOA
from qiskit.aqua import aqua_globals
from qiskit.aqua import QuantumInstance
from qiskit.optimization.applications.ising.common import sample_most_likely
from qiskit.optimization.algorithms import MinimumEigenOptimizer
from qiskit.optimization.problems import QuadraticProgram


w = np.array([[-1., 2., 0.],
 [0., -1., 2.],
 [0., 0., -1.]])


qubitOp, offset = stable_set.get_operator(w)
print('Offset:', offset)
print('Ising Hamiltonian:')
print(qubitOp.print_details())

# mapping Ising Hamiltonian to Quadratic Program
qp = QuadraticProgram()
qp.from_ising(qubitOp, offset)
qp.to_docplex().prettyprint()

aqua_globals.random_seed = np.random.default_rng(123)
seed = 10598
backend = Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')
quantum_instance = QuantumInstance(backend, seed_simulator=seed, seed_transpiler=seed)

qaoa = QAOA(quantum_instance=quantum_instance, p = 3)

# create minimum eigen optimizer based on qaoa
qaoa_optimizer = MinimumEigenOptimizer(qaoa)

# solve quadratic program
result = qaoa_optimizer.solve(qp)
print(result)
```

And it will give you this result

```
Offset: 0.5
Ising Hamiltonian:
IZZ (1+0j)
ZZI (1+0j)
IIZ (0.5+0j)
IZI (0.5+0j)
ZII (-1.5+0j)

// This file has been generated by DOcplex
// model name is: AnonymousModel
// single vars section
dvar bool x_0;
dvar bool x_1;
dvar bool x_2;

minimize
 [ - 3 x_0^2 + 4 x_0*x_1 - 5 x_1^2 + 4 x_1*x_2 + x_2^2 ] + 2;
 
subject to {

}
optimal function value: -3.0
optimal value: [0. 1. 0.]
status: SUCCESS
```

Hope this helps, please tell me if something is not clear and I'll explain better! :)

Comment: Hi Lena! Thanks so much - that's exactly what I was after. It has raised a couple more questions though, if you don't mind! First of all in the Ising Hamiltonian, what does the IZZ (1+0j) represent ? Secondly, how come the function to be minimised is different? I know it has the +2 offset but, even without this, it isn't equivalent to the expression. Finally, I didn't know about the `QuantumInstance` class, I thought you just put it an operator into the QAOA method. Having a look at the documentation, am I right in thinking QuantumInstance just provides simulation settings ?

Comment: @bubba I'm glad this is what you were looking for! So first, about the Ising hamiltonian, in optimization you usually start with a qubo and deal with bits. To make it understandable for the backend, you need to translate this with something it'll understand, here the Pauli gate Z, and you do this translation via the following bijective transformation ($x_i$ is the bit I, $Z_i$ is the gate applied to the Qubit i) : $x_i = \frac{1-Z_i}{2}$. By applying this to the qubo form, you'll get something like the sum of terms IZZ, ZZI, etc. we have here. Just a way to write the problem for the backend.

Comment: Next, the `QuantumInstance` is indeed a way to simulate your algorithm in the settings you want. It is quite useful if you want to simulate your Aqua algorithm in "real" conditions without having to use real devices, or play with the transpilation and execution via lots of parameters.

Comment: Finally about the form of the function to minimize, I'll admit I don't know, I'll try to look at it and get back to you here if I find anything useful about that! ;)

Comment: Hi @Lena, looking closer I don't think the use of the `stable_set.get_operator()` function works in this case. From the documentation, the function takes a numpy adjacency matrix which  the matrix `w' sure ain't: it's part of the QUBO formulation. I'm gonna have a look now, but I suspect it might be easier to write a function that takes this form of matrix into a docplex formulation and then use the qiskit converters ..... lots to do !

Comment: To be specific, I could just convert my networkx graph to a numpy array, and from there to the qiskit formulation, but I think I would lose the weighed detail of some of the nodes which is a bit of a problem for a weighed max independent set solver !

Comment: @bubba oups I think you are right, give me time to fix that indeed!

Comment: Hi ! I think I solved it for my particular case by just inputting the matrix as a quadractic term in the QuadracticProgram `minimise` function. It's equivalent (as far as I can tell!) because all the variables are binary. Do you think there will be any performance impacts because of this though ?

Comment: Hi Lena, I've come back to this now and I think `stable_set.get_operator' doesn't like normal adjacency matrices at all. I have edited my question to show how it doesn't work.